# installing tensorflow on anaconda (error occurred : matplotlib and user permission(13))

Tags: python, tensorflow

While installing tensorflow on anaconda version 5.3.0 cmd environtment by running `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`, it came up with the following error:

[click here for print screen of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW9PW.png)

I have tried following what others have said about `'This process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process - permission error(13)'` and run it on admin as has been suggested however still come up with the same errors in the above screenshot

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by installing python 3.6.7 (which was a downgrade from 3.7)